# getting undefined error in JavaScript building a table

Tags: javascript, undefined

My code works if I just output it to the screen.  But when I try to put the results into a table, the cell is filled in with Undefined.  I think it has to do with a scoping issue but I can't seem to get it worked out.  Can anyone help me understand the scoping involved here and where I am going wrong?

This is the one that doesn't work and gives the error:

```
var API_URL = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/hunt';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: API_URL,

        success: function(data) {
            data.Items.forEach(function(huntItem) {
                var table = document.getElementById("hunts");
                let row = table.insertRow(1);
                let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                let cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                let cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                let cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
                cell1.innerHTML = huntItem.Name;
                cell2.innerHTML = huntItem.l1h;
            })

        }
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>

    <h1>Hunting Results:</h1>

    <table id="hunts">
        <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Level 1</th>
            <th>Level 2</th>
            <th>Level 3</th>
            <th>Level 4</th>
            <th>Level 5</th>
        </tr>
        <div id="playerRow">

        </div>
    </table>
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Also, what does your base HTML page look like?

Comment: Please add `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));` just before `data.Items.forEach`, [edit] your question, and add one record of items to the question. It's likely that `Name` and/or `l1h` is not present on `huntItem`.

Comment: When I look in deeveloper tools Items has the data in it.  I'm going to add your line now.

Comment: Can you show us the response

Answer (score 0):

It was because I had a Name with a capital N. It should be named with a lowercase n.

```
cell1.innerHTML = huntItem.name;
cell2.innerHTML = huntItem.l1h;
```

This version works now!  What a rookie mistake!